# Having trouble getting shader to work with sprite batch in XNA #4

Tags: xna, shaders, directx, xna-4.0

I found a neat "CRT screen" effect shader on the web, but I've never used shaders before and I can't seem to get it working properly. If I do the second sprite batch in my code here normally without the effect of the shader, it renders fine. However, with the shader and the parameters I have provided, it just renders a few pixels up in the top left corner, where the faked "bezel" should be and sometimes the fake "screen" flashes one colour or an other.

Is there something wrong with the parameters I'm providing? I'm really stumped.

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        viewport = GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
        soldierFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("SpriteFont1");

        ShaderRenderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice, spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth, spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.None);
        WorkingTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);
        WorkingTexture1 = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);

        effect = Content.Load<Effect>(@"cgwg-xna");
        projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, viewport.Width, viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);
        halfPixelOffset = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
        effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(Matrix.Identity);
        effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(Matrix.Identity);
        effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(halfPixelOffset * projection);
        effect.Parameters["Worldview"].SetValue(Matrix.Identity * Matrix.Identity);
        effect.Parameters["ViewProjection"].SetValue((Matrix.Identity * (halfPixelOffset * projection)));
        effect.Parameters["WorldViewProjection"].SetValue((Matrix.Identity * (halfPixelOffset * projection)));
        effect.Parameters["WorkingTexture"].SetValue(WorkingTexture);
        effect.Parameters["WorkingTexture1"].SetValue(WorkingTexture1);
```

and then

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(ShaderRenderTarget);
        GraphicsDevice.Viewport = viewport;
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        //get rid of blurry sprites
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);

        if (_currScreen != null)
        {
            _currScreen.draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);

        spriteBatch.End();

        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        effect.Parameters["SourceTexture"].SetValue(ShaderRenderTarget);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearWrap, DepthStencilState.None, RasterizerState.CullNone, effect);
        spriteBatch.Draw(ShaderRenderTarget, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

the shader is pretty crazy and is as follows:

```
    // Matrix Definitions for Scaler Effects
    //

    matrix World                : WORLD;
    matrix View             : VIEW;
    matrix Projection           : PROJECTION;
    matrix Worldview            : WORLDVIEW;            // world * view
    matrix ViewProjection           : VIEWPROJECTION;       // view * projection
    matrix WorldViewProjection      : WORLDVIEWPROJECTION;      // world * view * projection

    //
    // Source Texture Definition for Scaler Effects
    //

    // Image Dimentions 
    float2 SourceDims : SOURCEDIMS = {1024.0F, 768.0F};

    // Size of one Texel
    float2 TexelSize  : TEXELSIZE = 1.0F/768.0F;

    //
    // Source Texture
    //
    texture SourceTexture               : SOURCETEXTURE;

    sampler SourceSampler = sampler_state {
        Texture   = (SourceTexture);
        MinFilter = POINT;
        MagFilter = POINT;
        MipFilter = NONE;
        AddressU  = Clamp;
        AddressV  = Clamp;
        SRGBTEXTURE = FALSE;
    };

    sampler BilinearSourceSampler = sampler_state {
        Texture   = (SourceTexture);
        MinFilter = LINEAR;
        MagFilter = LINEAR;
        MipFilter = NONE;
        AddressU  = Clamp;
        AddressV  = Clamp;
        SRGBTEXTURE = FALSE;
    };

    sampler SRGBSourceSampler = sampler_state {
        Texture   = (SourceTexture);
        MinFilter = POINT;
        MagFilter = POINT;
        MipFilter = NONE;
        AddressU  = Clamp;
        AddressV  = Clamp;
        SRGBTEXTURE = TRUE;
    };

    sampler SRGBBilinearSourceSampler = sampler_state {
        Texture   = (SourceTexture);
        MinFilter = LINEAR;
        MagFilter = LINEAR;
        MipFilter = NONE;
        AddressU  = Clamp;
        AddressV  = Clamp;
        SRGBTEXTURE = TRUE;
    };

    //
    // Working Texture and Working RenderTarget
    // Same Dims as Source Texture
    //
    texture WorkingTexture              : WORKINGTEXTURE;

    sampler WorkingSampler = sampler_state {
        Texture   = (WorkingTexture);
        MinFilter = POINT;
        MagFilter = POINT;
        MipFilter = NONE;
        AddressU  = Clamp;
        AddressV  = Clamp;
        SRGBTEXTURE = FALSE;
    };

    texture WorkingTexture1             : WORKINGTEXTURE1;

    sampler WorkingSampler1 = sampler_state {
        Texture   = (WorkingTexture1);
        MinFilter = POINT;
        MagFilter = POINT;
        MipFilter = NONE;
        AddressU  = Clamp;
        AddressV  = Clamp;
        SRGBTEXTURE = FALSE;
    };

    //
    // procedural textures that selects which pixel to generate
    //
    texture OutputSelectTexture
    < 
        string function = "GenerateOutputSelect";   // Function to generate from
        int width = 2;
        int height = 2;
    >;

    // TextureShader for the OutputSelectTexture
    float4 GenerateOutputSelect(float3 Pos : POSITION) : COLOR
    {
        float4 ret = (float4)1;
        if (Pos.x < 0.5 && Pos.y < 0.5) ret[0] = 0;
        else if (Pos.y < 0.5) ret[1] = 0;
        else if (Pos.x < 0.5) ret[2] = 0;
        else ret[3] = 0;
        return ret;
    }

    // Sampler for the OutputSelectTexture
    sampler OutputSelectSampler = sampler_state 
    {
        Texture   = (OutputSelectTexture);
        MinFilter = POINT;
        MagFilter = POINT;
        MipFilter = NONE;
        AddressU  = Wrap;
        AddressV  = Wrap;
        SRGBTEXTURE = FALSE;
    };

    //
    // A Simple Texture that can do a modulo (or frac) by a lookup, rather than by 
    // using a arithmetic instruction. Not entirely accurate
    //
    texture ModuloTexture
    < 
        string function = "GenerateModulo"; // Function to generate from
        int width = 16;
        int height = 16;
    >;

    // TextureShader for the ModuloTexture
    float4 GenerateModulo(float3 Pos : POSITION) : COLOR
    {
        return float4(Pos.x, Pos.y, 0, 0);
    }

    // Sampler for the ModuloTexture
    sampler ModuloSampler = sampler_state   
    {
        Texture   = (ModuloTexture);
        MinFilter = POINT;
        MagFilter = POINT;
        MipFilter = NONE;
        AddressU  = Wrap;
        AddressV  = Wrap;
        SRGBTEXTURE = FALSE;
    };

    // The name of this effect
    string name : NAME = "CRTFX";
    float scaling : SCALING = 1.0;

    // Comment the next line to disable interpolation in linear gamma (and gain speed).
    #define LINEAR_PROCESSING

    // Compensate for 16-235 level range as per Rec. 601.
    #define REF_LEVELS

    // Enable screen curvature.
    #define CURVATURE

    // Controls the intensity of the barrel distortion used to emulate the
    // curvature of a CRT. 0.0 is perfectly flat, 1.0 is annoyingly
    // distorted, higher values are increasingly ridiculous.
    #define distortion 0.05

    // Simulate a CRT gamma of 2.4.
    #define inputGamma  2.4

    // Compensate for the standard sRGB gamma of 2.2.
    #define outputGamma 2.2

    // Macros.
    #define FIX(c) max(abs(c), 1e-5);
    #define PI 3.141592653589

    #ifdef REF_LEVELS
    #       define LEVELS(c) max((c - 16.0 / 255.0) * 255.0 / (235.0 - 16.0), 0.0)
    #else
    #       define LEVELS(c) c
    #endif

    #ifdef LINEAR_PROCESSING
    #       define TEX2D(c) pow(LEVELS(tex2D(SourceBorderSampler, (c))), inputGamma)
    #else
    #       define TEX2D(c) LEVELS(tex2D(SourceBorderSampler, (c)))
    #endif

    //
    // Techniques
    //

    // combineTechnique: Final combine steps. Outputs to destination frame buffer
    string combineTechique : COMBINETECHNIQUE = "CRTFX";

    // preprocessTechnique: PreProcessing steps. Outputs to WorkingTexture
    //string preprocessTechique : PREPROCESSTECHNIQUE = "";

    struct VS_OUTPUT_PRODUCT
    {
        float4 Position     : POSITION;
        float2 pixel0       : TEXCOORD0;
        float2 pixel1       : TEXCOORD1;
        float2 abspos       : TEXCOORD2;
    };

    sampler SourceBorderSampler = sampler_state {
        Texture   = (SourceTexture);
        MinFilter = POINT;
        MagFilter = POINT;
        MipFilter = NONE;
        AddressU  = Clamp; //AddressU  = Border;
        AddressV  = Clamp; //AddressV  = Border;
        //SRGBTEXTURE = FALSE;
    };

    // vertex shader
    VS_OUTPUT_PRODUCT VS_Product(
        float3 Position : POSITION,
        float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0)
    {
        VS_OUTPUT_PRODUCT Out = (VS_OUTPUT_PRODUCT)0;

        // Do the standard vertex processing.
        Out.Position = mul(half4(Position, 1), WorldViewProjection);

        // Precalculate a bunch of useful values we'll need in the fragment
        // shader.

        // Texture coords.
        Out.pixel0 = TexCoord;

        // The size of one texel, in texture-coordinates.
        Out.pixel1 = TexelSize;

        // Resulting X pixel-coordinate of the pixel we're drawing.
        // Assumes (-0.5, 0.5) quad and output size in World matrix
        // as currently done in DOSBox D3D patch
        Out.abspos = float2((Position.x + 0.5) * World._11, (Position.y - 0.5) * (-World._22));

        return Out;
    }

    // Apply radial distortion to the given coordinate.
    float2 radialDistortion(float2 coord, float2 pos)
    {
        pos /= float2(World._11, World._22);
        float2 cc = pos - 0.5;
        float dist = dot(cc, cc) * distortion;
        return coord * (pos + cc * (1.0 + dist) * dist) / pos;
    }

    // Calculate the influence of a scanline on the current pixel.
    //
    // 'distance' is the distance in texture coordinates from the current
    // pixel to the scanline in question.
    // 'color' is the colour of the scanline at the horizontal location of
    // the current pixel.
    float4 scanlineWeights(float distance, float4 color)
    {
        // The "width" of the scanline beam is set as 2*(1 + x^4) for
        // each RGB channel.
        float4 wid = 2.0 + 2.0 * pow(color, 4.0);

        // The "weights" lines basically specify the formula that gives
        // you the profile of the beam, i.e. the intensity as
        // a function of distance from the vertical center of the
        // scanline. In this case, it is gaussian if width=2, and
        // becomes nongaussian for larger widths. Ideally this should
        // be normalized so that the integral across the beam is
        // independent of its width. That is, for a narrower beam
        // "weights" should have a higher peak at the center of the
        // scanline than for a wider beam.
        float4 weights = distance / 0.3;
        return 1.4 * exp(-pow(weights * rsqrt(0.5 * wid), wid)) / (0.6 + 0.2 * wid);
    }

    half4 PS_Product ( in VS_OUTPUT_PRODUCT input ) : COLOR
    {
        // Here's a helpful diagram to keep in mind while trying to
        // understand the code:
        //
        //  |      |      |      |      |
        // -------------------------------
        //  |      |      |      |      |
        //  |  01  |  11  |  21  |  31  | <-- current scanline
        //  |      | @    |      |      |
        // -------------------------------
        //  |      |      |      |      |
        //  |  02  |  12  |  22  |  32  | <-- next scanline
        //  |      |      |      |      |
        // -------------------------------
        //  |      |      |      |      |
        //
        // Each character-cell represents a pixel on the output
        // surface, "@" represents the current pixel (always somewhere
        // in the bottom half of the current scan-line, or the top-half
        // of the next scanline). The grid of lines represents the
        // edges of the texels of the underlying texture.

        // Texture coordinates of the texel containing the active pixel.
    #ifdef CURVATURE
        float2 xy = radialDistortion(input.pixel0, input.abspos);
    #else
        float2 xy = input.pixel0;
    #endif

        // Of all the pixels that are mapped onto the texel we are
        // currently rendering, which pixel are we currently rendering?
        float2 ratio_scale = xy * SourceDims - 0.5;
        float2 uv_ratio = frac(ratio_scale);

        // Snap to the center of the underlying texel.
        xy = (floor(ratio_scale) + 0.5) / SourceDims;

        // Calculate Lanczos scaling coefficients describing the effect
        // of various neighbour texels in a scanline on the current
        // pixel.
        float4 coeffs = PI * float4(1.0 + uv_ratio.x, uv_ratio.x, 1.0 - uv_ratio.x, 2.0 - uv_ratio.x);

        // Prevent division by zero.
        coeffs = FIX(coeffs);

        // Lanczos2 kernel.
        coeffs = 2.0 * sin(coeffs) * sin(coeffs / 2.0) / (coeffs * coeffs);

        // Normalize.
        coeffs /= dot(coeffs, 1.0);

        // Calculate the effective colour of the current and next
        // scanlines at the horizontal location of the current pixel,
        // using the Lanczos coefficients above.
        float4 col  = clamp(
                mul(coeffs, float4x4(
                        TEX2D(xy + float2(-input.pixel1.r, 0.0)),
                        TEX2D(xy),
                        TEX2D(xy + float2(input.pixel1.x, 0.0)),
                        TEX2D(xy + float2(2.0 * input.pixel1.x, 0.0))
                )), 0.0, 1.0);
        float4 col2 = clamp(
                mul(coeffs, float4x4(
                        TEX2D(xy + float2(-input.pixel1.x, input.pixel1.y)),
                        TEX2D(xy + float2(0.0, input.pixel1.y)),
                        TEX2D(xy + input.pixel1),
                        TEX2D(xy + float2(2.0 * input.pixel1.x, input.pixel1.y))
                )), 0.0, 1.0);

    #ifndef LINEAR_PROCESSING
        col  = pow(col , inputGamma);
        col2 = pow(col2, inputGamma);
    #endif

        // Calculate the influence of the current and next scanlines on
        // the current pixel.
        float4 weights  = scanlineWeights(uv_ratio.y, col);
        float4 weights2 = scanlineWeights(1.0 - uv_ratio.y, col2);
        float3 mul_res  = (col * weights + col2 * weights2).rgb;

        // dot-mask emulation:
        // Output pixels are alternately tinted green and magenta.
        float3 dotMaskWeights = lerp(
                float3(1.0, 0.7, 1.0),
                float3(0.7, 1.0, 0.7),
                floor(input.abspos.x % 2.0)
            );

        mul_res *= dotMaskWeights;

        // Convert the image gamma for display on our output device.
        mul_res = pow(abs(mul_res), 1.0 / outputGamma);

        // Color the texel.
        return half4(mul_res, 1.0);
    }

    technique CRTFX
    {
        pass P0
        {
            // shaders
            VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VS_Product();
            PixelShader  = compile ps_3_0 PS_Product();
            AlphaBlendEnable = FALSE;
            ColorWriteEnable = RED|GREEN|BLUE|ALPHA;
            //SRGBWRITEENABLE = FALSE;
        }
    }
```

The shader was originally made for emulators like DOSbox and was made by cgwg, Themaister, DOLLS and gulikoza

Answer (score 1):

I Googled extensively yesterday and today screwing around with a similar issue.
It turns out that, when using SpriteBatch with a custom effect that samples from textures, you must explicitly asign the textures to a register other than 0.

```
effect.Parameters["WorkingTexture"].SetValue(WorkingTexture);
```

1. SpriteBatch assigns this texture to register 0
2. SpriteBatch then assigns every other texure you've loaded to register 0
3. Spritebatch then assigns the "Source/Screen" texture to 0

Beta-testing occurs after release now-a-days... If and when you can get PIX to work, bludgeoning through your code with it is, occasionally, not a complete waste of time.
PIX is how i found this bug. Using PIX, verify that you have 2 or more occurences of

```
IDirect3DDeviceX::SetTexture(0, 0xXXXXXXXX)
```

between this draw and the previous. They will have other instructions between them. Once you have manually specified registers, one texture will remain assigned to 0 (screen texture) and the rest will be assigned elsewhere. In my case, they were internally assigned to 257, 0, and 3.

```
IDirect3DDeviceX::SetTexture(257, 0x07388110)
IDirect3DDeviceX::SetTexture(0, 0x07387EC0)
IDirect3DDeviceX::SetTexture(3, 0x07387E18)
```

Try this in your HLSL:

```
sampler WorkingSampler : register(s1) = sampler_state {
sampler WorkingSampler1 : register(s2) = sampler_state {
```

Or, try this (**not tested**) in your C#:

```
GraphicDevice.Textures[1] = WorkingTexture;
GraphicDevice.Textures[2] = WorkingTexture1;
```